# Convert JSON data from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

Good Morning !
I have a dataframe where the data source is a MongoDB JSON:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                                                 Id|Data                |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|{"":"7+197==","type":"03"} |       1651374000000|
|{"":"6/6==","type":"03"} |       1622419200000|
|{"":"0ℎ==","type":"03"}   |       1622419200000|
|{"":"6221/2==","type":"03"}  |       1622419200000|
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to convert the data to:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                                   Id |Data                |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 401148EE-9BA6-4BAA-B113-ED694B0F5BED | 2022-05-01 03:00:00|
| E90ED21E-C60F-412C-8305-DB5675DA7A5E | 2021-05-31 00:00:00|
| 7A1395BE-DEEB-410F-8B9A-5AF38DB86206 | 2021-05-31 00:00:00|
| 0CF3A84B-8648-4DC5-B639-B455D7F360D9 | 2021-05-31 00:00:00|
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

In Python, it is possible to convert the information with the code below:

```
id_bin = 'S6jzDEiGxU22ObRV1/Ng2Q=='
message_bytes = base64.b64decode(id_bin)

id = uuid.UUID(bytes_le=message_bytes)

data = (1622419200000 // 1000)
date_conv = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

pyspark running in a column of a dataframe does not work, can you help me?

Comment: [base64](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.base64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID can be computed using an `udf` and epoch to timestamp can be handled using `from_unixtime`.

> Your example included non-ascii characters however your python code included valid ASCII string, hence I have converted the input into valid ASCII.

```py
# Explicitly set time to UTC to get the timestamp in UTC
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import base64
import uuid

@F.udf(StringType())
def uuid_converter(data: str):
    message_bytes = base64.b64decode(data)
    res_uuid = uuid.UUID(bytes_le=message_bytes)
    return str(res_uuid).upper()


data = [({"binary":"7KgRQKabqkuxE+1pSw9b7Q==","type":"03"}, 1651374000000),
({"binary":"HtIO6Q/GLEGDBdtWddp6Xg==","type":"03"}, 1622419200000),
({"binary":"vpUTeuveD0GLmlrzjbhiBg==","type":"03"}, 1622419200000),
({"binary":"S6jzDEiGxU22ObRV1/Ng2Q==","type":"03"}, 1622419200000),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Id", "Data",))

df.withColumn("Id", uuid_converter(F.col("Id")["binary"]))\
  .withColumn("Data", F.from_unixtime(F.col("Data") / 1000))\
  .show(200, False)
```

### Output

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|Id                                  |Data               |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|4011A8EC-9BA6-4BAA-B113-ED694B0F5BED|2022-05-01 03:00:00|
|E90ED21E-C60F-412C-8305-DB5675DA7A5E|2021-05-31 00:00:00|
|7A1395BE-DEEB-410F-8B9A-5AF38DB86206|2021-05-31 00:00:00|
|0CF3A84B-8648-4DC5-B639-B455D7F360D9|2021-05-31 00:00:00|
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, I know that there is text with a value other than ASCII, because it's a problem I face too.
Thank you very much for the solution, it worked perfectly!

I had managed to do it using lambda...